# Update WAMP/Apache to use new cacert.pem

Tags: php, apache, wamp, ssl-certificate

Updated CA Cert: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I know I've done this on another machine but I can't find the resources that I found before when I had to perform this.

I want to update WAMP to use the .pem above, but I can't for the life of me remember where to do that with what command.

Comment: Do you mean so the various curl() functions have access to it?

Comment: Yes, so it's used by default so I don't have to put it in each CURL request.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're running at least php 5.3.7, you can put this in the ini at the end of your php.ini file:

```
curl.cainfo=c:\path\to\cacert.pem
```

You'll need to find the specific php.ini file for the version of php one you've selected to use.

A comment in the doc's show this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Here's the doc with the specific setting: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept as answer in 5 minutes when it allows me

Comment: @AndrewWilson  I use MAMP, so sorry if I cant tell you the exact path the ini or module file you need.

Comment: Actually I'm still needing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` how do I default fix that globally?

Comment: If you specify the certifo file in the correct ini file you shouldn't need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`  Besides, that is very unsafe.   Can you do a phpinfo() and see which INI file is being read?

Comment: @AndrewWilson Also, try leaving off the `[curl]` block declaration and putting just `curl.cainfo=c:\path\to\cacert.pem` at the end of your php.ini file

Comment: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini`, I have the code you have at the bottom (which I remember doing on another machine). but toggling the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` makes it successful/unsuccessful

Comment: Yes, by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  false it doens't check the validity of the peer, so it doesn't need a CACERT file.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and search for 'cacert' to find the comment I got this from

Comment: @AndrewWilson also, make sure you're php is >= 5.3.7 , otherwise it's not possible to set this via php.ini

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.3 I shouldn't have to do anything besides restart the WAMP service to reload the php.ini, correct?

Comment: Yes.  WAMP should be using mod php, so when apache restarts it should pick it up

Comment: Is there any other modules or anything that need to be loaded that I'm overlooking? besides curl

Comment: Here's the curl error I'm getting `error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: c:/wamp/cacert.pem CApath: none`

Comment: The error looks like it's at least trying to load it :)  how about with windows path notation (flipped slashes) `c:\wamp\cacert.pem`  Also make sure the permissions are such that wamp can read the contents of this file

Comment: It's set to everyone allowed to do everything to it (the .pem)... This is a strong reminder on why I've been using a mac for so long :P

Comment: It was the CA Cert file!!!! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt worked. @Ray you deserve a beer for trying to stick with me through the end on this one

Comment: How do I do this if my PHP version is 5.3.1.x (e.g lower than the 5.3.7 state above)

Comment: You may also have to store this same value as `openssl.cafile`, if you have PHP make SSL connections that aren't done by curl.

Comment: I'm on WAMP 3.2.0. I had to use the ca-bundle.crt instead of cacert.pem and configure `openssl.cafile = C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.11/extras/ssl/ca-bundle.crt`.