# eWAY payment gateway integration

Tags: payment, gateway

I been searching this error and i have no luck on finding a solution. I am new in this eway payment gateway. I am just trying to understand the process of how to integrate eway payment into php.

i started to follow the sample code given by [eway SDK](https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/php) but when i test it

> Error: eWAY library has encountered a problem connecting to Rapid.

Maybe i just got confused that hindered me to find the correct solution.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to solve this problem?

Many thanks,

Comment: Looks like you've encountered a connection issue. You can try enabling logging as described [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/incarnate/bfddd8fc31281bacb8d4) to get the root error.

Comment: Where these error will be listed?

Comment: That gist will log to PHP's error log using error_log(). Usually this will be in Apache's error log, but it will depend on your host

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is update your certificate.

On your server upload this file - https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Make sure its not in your www folder, somewhere only apache can access.

Then in your php.ini file add this line to the bottom:

curl.cainfo=C:\wamp\certificates\cacert-2016-11-02.pem

Replace C:\wamp\certificates\cacert-2016-11-02.pem with the path of the certificate you just uploaded. Restart your server. It should now start working.

Here is some more information:

[Update WAMP/Apache to use new cacert.pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169623/update-wamp-apache-to-use-new-cacert-pem)

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html