# cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I am using Firebase php SDK [link](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and working with laravel latest version on XAMMP server on windows 10 but when i try to use Firebase APi using above php SDK i get this error.i download .pem certificate manually but still not working

**Error**

```
Kreait \ Firebase \ Exception \ ApiException
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
Previous exceptions
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (0)
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions? See [link](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESSLCACERTBADFILE)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169623/update-wamp-apache-to-use-new-cacert-pem

Comment: in the php.ini file:
curl.cainfo ="C:\Users\XYZUSER\cacert.pem", where cacert.pem is the file downloaded from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html  AND keep
;openssl.capath
;openssl.cafile    COMMENTED ONLY (are commented out by default)

Answer (score 18):

In your case, simply do this

Open your php.ini file and update this

```
;openssl.cafile=
```

with

```
openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

---

For others who might face this error, follow this:

It has to do with your cURL certification. Take these steps:

1. Head over to `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`. This link gets you (downloads) the latest cacert.pem file.
2. Use this command on your terminal on the application you are currently working on so that you would know the exact PHP used in cases of multiple installations of PHP on your computer, `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`. This shows you the exact location of the php.ini file for the current application you are running. For instance, mine is `C:\php-7.4.11\php.ini`. Note this location as we will use it soon.
3. Go into this location `C:\php-7.4.11` ie. the folder containing the php.ini file in my case, open "extras", open "ssl" (for clarity sake, mine looks like this `C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl`). In this folder, paste in the newly downloaded cacert.pem file from Step 1 above.
4. Right-click on the cacert.pem file and unblock it from "Properties" as it could complain of coming from another computer. Still on this Properties section pop-up, copy the new file location link from the "Security" section (mine is `C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem` ensure to copy yours). You can also copy this from the file browser header.
5. Go to this location `C:\php-7.4.11\php.ini` (this is my php.ini location. Go to yours) and update the following 2 fields on your php.ini file.

   ;curl.cainfo =

   ;openssl.cafile=

with

```
curl.cainfo ="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

openssl.cafile="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

6. Restart your xampp/wamp server. In my case, I also restart every other server running.

NB: You get cURL 60 error if `curl.cainfo` is not updated. And cURL 77 if `openssl.cafile` is not updated.

Also, do not forget to uncomment the `;` before `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafil`e.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maximillian Raphaels !

Comment: You're welcome, @Ale DC. I'm happy this was helpful.

Comment: How come it always comes down to file security? Anyway, thanks for the post, really helped me

Comment: @Chris Adzima  It's simply enforcing the right procedure to ensure secure apps, I suppose. You're welcome!

Comment: @Chris Adzima For a more practical view, I encountered this hitch while working on a payment application on my local machine. The cURL provides (stands as) the local (development server's) "HTTPS". Whereas on a live server, you must have your SSL certificate (HTTPS for secure SSL/TLS connections (not HTTP)) activated (e.g. payment channels like Stripe, PayPal would enforce this for payment to pull through). This ensures that sensitive data sent and received are encrypted and sent/received via secure SSL/TLS connections...

Comment: ... In my application I was working on for instance, we wouldn't want peoples' payment details not to be encrypted and sent via insecure connections. A security concern, no?     Tried to explain the best way I could. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

In my case using MAMP PRO I had this error :

```
CURL error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem
  CApath: none
```

The file /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem was a symlink to /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem

it appeared that the file was here but seems to be corrupted or out of date.

I downloaded the new one from [here](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) and replaced it. Then it worked again.

Comment: This worked for the normal version of MAMP too

Comment: The link for cacert.pem died. In my case, I download the latest version of Mamp whose cacert.pem is updated along.